# Can't use IsOptional and Transform decorator at the same time in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, dto, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm trying to create an optional field with a default value in a nest dto class. So far I've done this for my specific field (if the field is present, use the field, otherwise use `2`):

```
@Transform((value) => value || 2)
@IsOptional()
@IsNumber()
monitorBackgroundInterval: number
```

I have double check that Validation pipe are use globally in my application, so the transform would be called when using my route:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
```

But I think the `@Optional` decorator is taking on the `@Transform` decorator, I've tried to log inside the transform and it isn't called.
When trying my route, and logging the dto, the field doesn't appeared at all, so the transform isn't working properlly.

I know this is possible so I'm pretty sure it's a mistake of mine.

Is there a specific order to respect in order to make it works ? Have I missed something ?

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are setting a default value of 2, that means the field will always have a value, so @IsOptional is not required.